# Get index of first true value in list of bool

Tags: flutter, dart

```
     ListView(
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    children: <Widget>[
      ToolControlButton(
        onPressed: () => onControlPress(0),
        isSelected: selectedControl[0],
        icon: Icons.category,
        text: 'Option1',
      ),
      ToolControlButton(
        onPressed: () => onControlPress(1),
        isSelected: selectedControl[1],
        icon: Icons.category,
        text: 'Option2',
      ),
      ToolControlButton(
        onPressed: () => onControlPress(2),
        isSelected: selectedControl[2],
        icon: Icons.category,
        text: 'Option3',
      ),
      ToolControlButton(
        onPressed: () => onControlPress(3),
        isSelected: selectedControl[3],
        icon: Icons.category,
        text: 'Option4',
      )
    ],
  )
```

I've got List of Booleans

```
List<bool> selectedControl = [true, false, false, false];
```

And list of Widgets

```
List<Widget> cont = [
Container(color: Colors.red),
Container(color: Colors.green,
Container(color: Colors.orange),
Container(color: Colors.blue)
];
```

I want to display cont widget at the index where selectedControl has true value. This is what I managed to do so far and it works. Is there any better way of doing it for this purpose?

```
return cont[selectedControl.indexWhere((selected) => selected == true)],
```

Comment: why don't you keep just index of selected item instead of list of booleans?

Comment: Hi Eugen. I've just edited my question. Basically I'm using list of selectedControl to make list tile in list view selected which is on the left side of the screen and according to this I can display appropriate window on the right which is list of containers.. Hope that makes it clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return cont[selectedControl.indexWhere((selected) => selected == true)];
```

This will work because this is just the opposite of [firstWhere](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/firstWhere.html) where the first **element** which satisfies the condition is met. `indexWhere` is the equivalent of `firstWhere` but it only returns an index of the **first** met condition. However, If none selected is true then `indexWhere` returns `-1` and that will cause an out of bounds exception.

You could write your code like this:

```
final selectedControlIndex = selectedControl.indexWhere((selected) => selected);
return selectedControlIndex >= 0? cont[selectedControlIndex] : Container();
```

Comment: Thanks Shababb. I wasn't sure if finding an index of the first true value in the list is the best for this case. Thank you again

Comment: Welcome. Don't forget to upvote the answer for the answer to have higher visibility. Thanks.